# CSS word-wrap causes whitespace overflow after div

Tags: css, internet-explorer, html, word-wrap

I'm using the CSS word-wrap property (set to break-word) to display a single no-spaced string in its entirety within a div element of fixed width and variable height. The div element itself is within a table cell `<td>`. The word break works as expected, breaking the word at the defined fixed width. However, in IE9 (with IE7 document standards), there appears to be some extra space after the div, causing the table cell to extend in width (not desired). The div width itself appears to be correct, as specified by its CSS. I used borders around the div and table cell to verify. I've tried explicitly setting the table cell width (and max-width) but neither approach works. This behaviour is not observed in Firefox or Chrome.

Edit: Added sample code [here](http://jsfiddle.net/gmDpe/5/). The problem only occurs with IE (Browser_Mode=IE9; Document_Mode=IE7).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently the `td` is making room for the full length of the word, as though it weren't breaking.  You can prevent this by setting `overflow: hidden` on the div.

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gmDpe/6/

Answer (score 1):

I came across a similar problem once.
Have you tried to use `table-layout : fixed` on your table element ?

[table-layout](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/tables.html#propdef-table-layout) is a very little known but [widely supported](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/tables.html#t03) property which can be quite helpful in cases like this.

Comment: Thanks for your input. However, the table-layout property wasn't able to fix the problem.

Comment: Really ? I used `table-layout: fixed` on the example you submitted and it was looking like it should in IE7.

Comment: Yes, this property indeed resolves the example I provided. My production table doesn't actually have an explicitly-defined width, which is probably why table-layout didn't work there. Thanks.